# How to check a condition once when using multiple "depends"?

Tags: ant

I want to have a 'master' ant target which depends on multiple "worker targets", (each of which does "one thing well")

However, I want to conditionally execute the "master" target, i.e. and not execute the "worker' subtargets if the condition is not met

(specficially, the master target creates and populates the database. The subtarget creates schema, populates tables, etc. The final step in the master target leaves a marker file to indicate "database created once." On subsequent runs, the process should not try to create the database.

### The question

How can I implement this in a manner both "antish" (i.e. without "antcall) and DRY (dont' repeat yourself).

### Example

```
<target name="check-db-created">
    <available file="db.created.marker.txt" property="db.already.created"/>
</target>

<target name="create-new-db" 
        unless="db.already.created"
        depends="check-db-created,create-db-mssql,create-tables,compile-sp,disable-constraints.....">
</target>

<target name="create-db-mssql" >
   ..do stufff
</target>
```

### Comments

The issue is that the 'sub-targets' ('create-db-mssql', create-tables', etc) execute even though the "master" target does not need to run. Ant documentation clearly discusses this.

> Important: the if and unless attributes only enable or disable the
>   target to which they are attached. They do not control whether or not
>   targets that a conditional target depends upon get executed. In fact,
>   they do not even get evaluated until the target is about to be
>   executed, and all its predecessors have already run.

I can code around the rpoblem by adding "unless" clauses to all the 'worker targets', but would like to avoid repeating.

Additionally, I use antcall as follows, but would prefer to avoid the "GOTO" of the ant world.

```
<target name="create-new-db" depends="check-db-created"
        unless="db.already.created">
  <antcall target="create-new-db-internal"/>
</target> 

<target name="create-new-db-internal"
        depends="create-db,create-tables,compile-sp,disable-constraints,insert-base-data,insert-installer-generated-sql,insert-kb-data"
>
</target>
```

thanks